# php (array)-> mysql (multiple rows with a foreign key) Update specific row in table where id and row number varies

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$schoolinfo = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE table SET firstname=?, lastname=? from school where   foreignkey='$id'");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($schoolinfo,'ss', $firstname, $lastname)


for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['row']);$i++){     
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname'][$i]);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname'][$i]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($schoolinfo);
}
```

This updates all rows with the same firstname and lastname.

I want to update rows from selection where foreignkey = '$id' and rownumber ='i'

Any queries or subqueries  out there?

Comment: You should _not_ use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when using `bind_param`. You'll end up escaping twice.

Comment: You're repeatedly updating the same row, there's no `rownumber` in your query.

Comment: @Barmar i just exactly edited it barmar same issue

Comment: Foreign keys only, no Ids. Table has multiple rows with same foreign key. I want to post the info from array into the correct rows.

Answer (score 1):

just remove this `from school` from your update query and give a name to your table .

like that

```
 $schoolinfo = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE school SET firstname=?, lastname=? where   foreignkey='$id'");
```

you mixed between SELECT  and UPDATE.

i dont know if im wrong or , you have binded firstname and lastname before the loop .

try this

```
$schoolinfo = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE school SET firstname=?, lastname=? WHERE foreignkey='$id'");

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['row']);$i++){     
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($schoolinfo,'ss', $firstname, $lastname)
mysqli_stmt_execute($schoolinfo);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to bind in the loop. `bind_param` uses references.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$schoolinfo = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE school SET firstname=?, lastname=?
                                    WHERE foreignkey=? and rownumber = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($schoolinfo,'sssi', $firstname, $lastname, $id, $i);

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['row']);$i++){     
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($schoolinfo);
}
```

You didn't have `rownumber` in the query. And it's best to use `bind_param` for all variables that you're substituting.

Comment: I need to create the rownumber it doesn't exist in the table

Comment: I am pretty sure I have to use a SELECT subquery here to create the row_number()

Comment: If you search SO for `[mysql] rownumber` you will find examples of that. But you need an ordering criteria for your table, otherwise the row number assignments will be random.

Comment: I'm a little confused, though. Isn't the `id` field a unique identifier? How can there be multiple rows with the same `id`?